# Stick image to the div bottom

Tags: css

I have one div that should contain text and bellow it one image.
I don't want that image to ever go out of that div. Just to the bottom.
That image maximum should be 128px.
But when text on top of the div is too large image should become smaller.
I have tried something but this stick image to the bottom of the browser:

```
<div style="width:250px; height:300px;background:#ff0000;">
    <div style="background:#00ff00;">hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/></div>
    <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.joystiq.com/media/2008/07/ea.logo.round.490.jpg" style="position: absolute;
                                                                                                 bottom: 0;
                                                                                                 set left: 0;
                                                                                                 height: 24px;"/>
  </div>
```

**Update**

```
<div style="width:250px; height:300px;background:#ff0000;">
    <div style="background:#00ff00;">hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>
hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hjg<br/>jhg</div>
    <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.joystiq.com/media/2008/07/ea.logo.round.490.jpg" style="position: relative;bottom: 0;left: 0; height:100%;"/>
  </div>
```

**Update**
http://jsfiddle.net/jjehN/

Comment: just like Jonas said, the container DIV must have position: relative; and also, Why have you put "set left: 0;"? Don't know if its a typo or not. I've never seen anyone use "set left" as it should be just "left" and I couldn't find it using google either. So I'ld suggest changing that from "set left" to "left"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE:
For your needs use "`float`" instead.  Remember to use the "`clear`" after floats so you dont break the page. Heres your code, working with textwrapping

```
<div style="position:relative;width:250px; min-height:300px;background:#ff0000;">
    <div style="background:#00ff00;">hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hjg<br/>jhg</div>

            <img src="http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1306369561351/recent/miscellaneousimprovements-1/android_icon_128.png"style="float:bottom;
                      bottom: 0;left: 0; background:#0000ff;max-height: 100%;"/>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
```

For making the picture shrink/grow. Use Javascript. Maybe jQuery will be easiest for you. Make a new tread here at Stackoverflow if you find any troubles using it.

Best Regards
Jonas

Comment: I updated question. image still doesn't shrink if top content is too large.

Comment: If I remove 100% then image goes out of div :(

Comment: I added relative to the top div and absolute to the image and now image doesn't cross bottom but goes over the top text.

Comment: I have added it at the end of question

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:250px; height:300px;background:#ff0000;position: relative;">
  <div style="background:#00ff00;">hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>
    hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hello<br/>hjg<br/>jhg</div>
  <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.joystiq.com/media/2008/07/ea.logo.round.490.jpg" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0; height:100%;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @1110 asks how to get the image to shrink when the content gets too large. This only helps position the image at the bottom of the div.